# Do Lua variables lose their value between script calls?

Tags: scripting, variables, lua

In a C app when I call a Lua script, do the variables in the code stay with the same value when I call the script again later?

Comment: Slightly related, but are you initializing these variables on first use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They will still exist in the lua state you created until you close that state.  The variables are tied to the state not the script file.

*edit*

As noted in the comments local variables will be garbage collected when they go out of scope.  A further caveat is that Lua supports [closures and upvalues](http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html) so the scope may not always be completely obvious.

Comment: I would caveat that by stating that *global* variables remain with the Lua state. Local variables within the Lua script will be garbage collected.

Comment: and of course upvalues (external locals) stay with the functions in the lua state that they belong to, until the functions can be garbage collected.